# How to create an image app for iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, image-processing, uiimage

I was wondering how to go about creating an image app for the iphone. I know how to create an iphone app. I was just wondering what the best way to make an image app is. I want the user to be able to import an image, and then the app will add an effect to it like blur it or tint it or warp it. How can I do this? I've been searching forever. Please help.

Comment: dude you question is way not clear at all...

Answer (score 0):

I encourgae you to look into a few image processing libraries for iOS that are out there. A search on Google will return a few options..

Here's one > http://mobileorchard.com/a-simple-iphone-image-processing-library/

You should also look into the sample code provided by Apple on GLImageProcessing > http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html

Regarding importing pictures into your app; there are several examples out there on how to do so through the UIIMagePickerController. Here's one > 
http://maniacdev.com/2010/02/uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-camera/