# photo scroll view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I need to make photo app like photo app in ios. I need to have uiscrollview and custom buttons inside it. So is it any tutorial about how to do this or code cause i saw a lot of apps are using this feature.
Thank you

Comment: This wil help you https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser

Comment: it is very good example but i need a lot of small pictures before i will show them in full size. so user can see them before choose

Comment: Can you show us some code you have already written? Or where you've searched? Or are you just using us to do your research for you?

Comment: I loook here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382637/how-to-create-an-image-app-for-iphone and here http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/10716-develop-iphone-photo-app.html but this didn't help me

Comment: You're just lazy. Did you even try Googling for "photo scroll view ios tutorial"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also have a look at the Three20 library which provides a photo gallery component. Look at the tutorial [How To Use the Three20 Photo Viewer](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer) for a better understanding since the documentation of the Three20 library is still not existing on their homepage.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

Add buttons.  And check the UIScrollView reference next time.